# iOS App loader - what file type should be uploaded

Tags: ios, app-store

I have always been uploading iOS apps to appstore from XCode Organizer. That is pretty simple process. And we do not see any IPA or APP file is created. Now my client is trying himself to upload the app using app loader and is continuously asking for an IPA file. Now I have some specific questions -

1. Does app loader exist now-a-days ? Is it a different program out of XCode?
2. If it does, what file it takes from me to upload to appstore? An IPA?
3. How do I create the file for appstore? Note that I have the distribution certificate and appstore provisioning files installed and set in my release configuration. And I am sure if I have tried with XCode it would upload already. But, client not allowing me to do that. He will do it using app loader.

Special Notes - 
1. Please do not give me links to an apple documentation, they do not talk about file type and how to create that. They always say "binary". Their doc titles does not reflect the content.
2. Please do not show me the Ad Hoc build process, that is not what I am asking.
3. Please only reply if you have used app loader before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application Loader is present in the Utilties folder.
For XCode 4.5 go to 
XCode -> Right Click and select Show Package Contents
then go to Contents -> Applications -> Application Loader.

When you just do a build from Xcode, you get .app file.
To create .ipa from it follow below process:

1. On "/" create a folder named Payload
2. Copy your .app and .mobileprovision files in this folder.
3. Open terminal, go to / and run following command
   zip -9 -y -r appName.ipa Payload/

This will create file "appName.ipa" on /

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the right binary. But Even though I have set the Appstore profile (and distribution certificate) in build settings Client is getting this error at the time of uploading the IPA- "application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements or was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate".

Comment: Just make sure your selected distribution profile and the one you put in the "Payload" folder are same and correct.

Comment: How to copy .app file to the / folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes and Yes.
2. As far as I know, it takes a compressed .app file.
3. In Xcode go to Products and select "show in finder". Then compress the file with a right click. The result should be uploaded with application loader. The result is located in the Library directory. Depending on your settings this can be hidden from application loader. Therefore you should copy the compressed file to a directory which is accessible from any program (like the desktop).

Comment: Thanks. But it did not help. I set the appstore provisioning then clean and build. Found the <app_name>.app file. Opened it in finder and zipped it. Now I have the <app_name>.app.zip file, this does not uplaod. Also, manually changed the extension <app_name>.ipa to the same file. It did not upload. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't upload in the holiday shot down of the App Store. You have to wait until the 29th of december. Then prepare in iTunes Connect the app for an upload (or update) and try again.