# .app file not getting dragged into Itunes folder

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, itunes

I want to generate the .ipa file for App download. I am executing code in xcode 4.5.2 and after build success, dragging the .app file to itunes folder. But, the drag itself is not happening. My device has IOS 5.1.Do i need to upgrade my device OS to IOS6 or any other reaon is the cause. Can anybody tell me, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

For the method to generate .ipa file from .app file 
see my answer to this question:

[iOS App loader - what file type should be uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986710/ios-app-loader-what-file-type-should-be-uploaded/13986830#13986830)

Comment: How to copy .app file to the '/' folder because the .app file is not getting dragged to itunes folder.. Where should i drag it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot drag an .app file to iTunes. You can drag an .ipa file however.

To create the .ipa file in Xcode:

1. Run Product / Archive. If successful, it switches to the Organizer window.
2. Click "Distribute...", select "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" and continue the wizard until you're asked to save the .ipa file.

The saved .ipa file can then be dragged to iTunes and synchronized to your device.

For uploading the app to the Apple' App Store, you don't need to explicitly create an .ipa file. You can be directly upload from the Organizer windows using the same "Distribute..." button.

Comment: For me product/archive is failing.. What could be the reason?

Comment: How am I supposed to know why it's failing if you don't give any details? How and when does it fail? What error message does it give?

Comment: I was running xcode 4.5.2 on device having IOS 5.1. i think that is the reason why it failed. I need ipa file working in IOS 6. So, is it necessary to upgrade by device OS also to 6.0 to generate the ipa file?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. It depends on the details of the error you don't want to share with us.